# Cannot add image texture to UV unwrap?

Tags: modeling

New to Blender, trying to load an image texture into the Diffuse channel instead of a colour to learn to UV unwrap. Quite simply I do not have the button needed to the right of the colour bar in materials to open the drop down menu with the image texture option in it, why is that? Using 2.79

thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand what you have. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)).

Answer (score 0):

I was in Blender Render and not Cycles